# WPF app, problem with NotifyIcon (Forms)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, notifyicon

I have problem with tray icon in `WPF`.
Now i using `NotifyIcon` from windows forms, but this control not accepting
`ContextMenu` from `WPF`. I must use `ContextMenu` from `XAML` because i will be not
doing other globalization code for only this control from *Windows.Forms* (all app is in *WPF*) 
and application must be strongly multilanguage. How to solve this?

1. How to make `Tray` icon from *WPF* not Windows *Forms*?
2. How to bind `ContextMenu` from *WPF* to `NotifyInfo` control from *Forms*.
3. or other way to solve this.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this solution on CodePlex](http://wpfcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyIcon&referringTitle=Home)